Error: control.registerOnChange is not a function with reactive form
I am trying to get the mat-select to open with 'tag2' selected. It works with a string[] but not with { id: number; name: string }[].
  tags: { id: number; name: string }[] = [{ id: 1, name: 'tag1' }, { id: 2, name: 'tag2' }, { id: 3, name: 'Jack' }];

  form = this.fb.group({
    loadSettings: this.fb.group({
      test: this.fb.group({
          id: [2, Validators.required],
          name: ['tag2', Validators.required],
      }),
}),  });

<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div formGroupName="loadSettings">
    <div class="au-mat-column-lg-px" style="padding-top: 76px;">
      <mat-form-field class="full-width">
        <mat-select [compareWith]="compareFn" formControlName="test">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of tags" [value]="option">
            <span>{{ option.name }}</span>
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-15-starter-pack-dxetmw
Any help much appreciated!

You are getting the error "Error: control.registerOnChange is not a function with reactive form", because the ts form control name, does not match the formControlName attribute value you have in the HTML.
I am not sure why you need two formGroups, but we can use the ID to set the tag value, you do not need a formGroup for each id and name, instead just a single value id will be used for selection.
HTML:
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div formGroupName="loadSettings">
    <div class="au-mat-column-lg-px" style="padding-top: 76px;">
      <mat-form-field class="full-width">
        <!-- <mat-label>Revision Tag</mat-label> -->
        <mat-select formControlName="test">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of revisionTags" [value]="option.id">
            <span>{{ option.name }}</span>
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

TS:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  revisionTags: { id: number; name: string }[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'tag1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'tag2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Jack' },
  ];
  //revisionTags: string[] = ['Jack', 'Tom', 'Donald'];

  form = this.fb.group({
    loadSettings: this.fb.group({
      //test: ['Tom', Validators.required],
      test: [1, Validators.required],
    }),
  });

  compareFn(o1: any, o2: any): boolean {
    // if (o2 === null) {
    //     return false;
    // }
    return o1.id === o2.id;
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

I think this can be done by using just one form group/form control for the test. You can just save the id instead of storing the whole object. Here's what you can update to have the tag2 option be selected by default:
TS Code (Only the part that you need to update
    form = this.fb.group({
        loadSettings: this.fb.group({
          test: [2, Validators.required],
        }),
    });
    
    compareFn(o1: any, o2: any): boolean {
        return o1 === o2;
    }

HTML
    <mat-select [compareWith]="compareFn" formControlName="test">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of revisionTags" [value]="option.id">
            <span>{{ option.name }}</span>
          </mat-option>
    </mat-select>

With these changes, the id of the selected option will be stored in the form which you can use later for form submission and what not.
